# How to match rownumber to another table in SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I do have a following code:

```
select distinct(code||'_'||indicator||'_'||lenght) as combination,rownum
from my_table
(select *
from my_table)
```

This returns me unique combinations with row numbers. Now I want to match those rownumbers with table "my_table", to fetch all columns in table only for those specific row numbers, which are matching the "combination"...I have no idea how. The whole idea is that I have this table (my_table) and I want to select only rows, which are unique (based on the combination above).

Comment: so to summarize what you said, you are trying to get the rows that have values in those three columns as unique?

Comment: Please share some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

> This returns me unique combinations with row numbers.

No, it does not. `DISTINCT` is not a function, it applies to all the columns of the `SELECT` clause including `ROWNUM` so you will end up returning every row because duplicates of `code`, `indicator` and `length` will be assigned different `ROWNUM` values so there will be no `DISTINCT` rows within the result set.

If you want all the unique combinations then use `DISTINCT` first and apply `ROWNUM` second on an in-line view:

```sql
SELECT m.*,
       ROWNUM
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         code,
         indicator,
         length
  FROM   my_table
) m;
```

> Now I want to match those rownumbers with table "my_table", to fetch all columns in table only for those specific row numbers, which are matching the "combination".

The explanation is a little confused but you appear to want return a single row for each `code`, `indicator` and `length` combination and to return all the columns for that row. Use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT m.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY code, indicator, length ORDER BY something)
           AS rn
  FROM   my_table m
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

*`something` could be another column, `ROWNUM` or a literal value such as `1`.*